# Is it not possible to use FormData.append in a loop?

Tags: javascript, form-data

This is an ajax call that is able to get current time and change to string with the format that users needed.
Because I want to encapsulate the ajax call, I made an array with key-value pairs.  I want to use `formData.append` to put parameters to make an Ajax call.
I wrote some code shown below but when I passed an array with only 1 object,
after `formdata.append` executed, `formdata` is still empty, and make my ajax call unable to get my ideal result.
Could I know where I was wrong?

```
var Data=[{ "NAME": "DATEFORMAT", "VALUE": "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" }];
var formData = new FormData();
for (var i = 0; i < Data.length; i += 1) {
    var x=Data[i];
    formData.append(x.NAME, x.VALUE);
}
$.ajax({
    url: "SomeFunction.ashx",
    headers: {
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "Requested-Type": "DateTimeToString"
    },
    method: "post",
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (retdata) {
        resolve(retdata);
    },
    error: function (err) {
        reject(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you add your `Data` values too?

Comment: [{ "NAME": "DATEFORMAT", "VALUE": "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" }]

Comment: How did you check the values?

Comment: I found that when I started the Ajax call ,I received NULL at my back end, so I started using Google Chrome DevTools to step by step.  I found that when I executed that command,  formData is still null.

Comment: You are not using your FormData here. You are only sending a string, the result of `JSON.stringify(Data)`.

Comment: I am sorry that I posted different code.  Now I change my code to the state that my problems occurs.

Comment: @GaryLu after the `formdata.append(x.NAME, x.VALUE)` what happens if you add an `console.log(formData.get(x.NAME))`?

Comment: @OliverNybo "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"

Comment: @GaryLu then the data is successfully being appended to **formData**, your problem is with your **ajax request**.

Comment: @GaryLu Happy to help, I'm gonna write it up as an answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, your **for loop** and `formData` is working just fine.

If you add a `console.log(formData.get(x.NAME))` inside the **for loop**, you will see, that the data is successfully being appended to the `formData` element.

So your problem is in your **ajax request**.

```js
var Data=[{ "NAME": "DATEFORMAT", "VALUE": "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" }];
var formData = new FormData();
for (var i = 0; i < Data.length; i += 1) {
    var x=Data[i];
    formData.append(x.NAME, x.VALUE);
    console.log(formData.get(x.NAME));
}
```