# 500 (Internal Server Error) when sending file using Axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am trying to send file using Axios in Laravel and Vuejs. All the data stored in `variantsProd` variable below:

```
data() {
    return {
        form: new Form({
            variantsProd: [],
            imagesFile: [],
        }),
        
    };
},
```

The `variantsProd` contains below data:
[image]

The problem is in `imagesFile` attribute. It's contain a file. If I keep `imagesFile` with empty value `[]` it's working, all data can be sent. But if I attach an image/s, I always get 500 (Internal Server Error). I have no idea why does this happens?

```
 let getImg = [];
        this.form.variantsProd.forEach((item) => {
            let totalImagesFile = $('.images' + item.id)[0].files.length; //Total Images
            let imagesFile = $('.images' + item.id)[0];
            for (let i = 0; i < totalImagesFile; i++) {
                getImg.push(imagesFile.files[i]);
            }
            //this.imagesFile = getImg;
            this.form.imagesFile = getImg;
        });

        this.form
            .post('api/staff/products/store', {
                header: {
                    'Content-Type': 'content-type':
                        'multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------974767299852498929531610575',
                },
            })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                if (this.form.isVariantExists > 0) {
                    this.validateVariants(response);
                } else {
                    this.$router.push({ name: 'products-index' });
                    this.showSuccessMsg(response);
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
                swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: 'Oouch...',
                    text: 'Something went wrong! Make sure you input the valid data!',
                    footer: '<a href>Why do I have this issue?</a>',
                });
            })
            .finally(() => {
                $('#loadingButton').attr('disabled', false);
                $('.proc-regis').remove();
                $('#loadingButton').html(`Save`);
            });
```

FYI:
I am using `bootstrap-fileinput` in this case.

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54519998/upload-multiple-file-with-vue-js-and-axios/54520177

Comment: @mk21: Please review my question. I've just update with some detail.

Comment: as stated, 500 return code means the server does not know how to handle your request. Maybe the server does not know how to handle binary files? Maybe it is expecting simple strings inside `images[]` as image url? do you have access to server or any documentation of it so that you can verify what the server endpoint is expecting?

Comment: How can I access to server or any documentation of it? I use XAMPP phpmyadmin for my localhost server. 

I am trying to find another solution. Is this possible with this way? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56215357/is-it-not-possible-to-use-formdata-append-in-a-loop/56217038

Comment: you are sending your `POST` request to `api/staff/products/store`. Do you own/maintain this api? what does it look like? This address is the one rejecting your request.

Comment: Yes. This is my API. Sending text is ok, but the problem in sending file. In `api/staff/products/store` controller, I only return the message. If it success it will return the message. That's it

Comment: I see. do you see any exceptions, errors..etc. on this controller when an upload happens? The thing is the 500 error comes from your server, so the problem most likely lies within this api, not your vue section. It might be a good start to inspect the request within your api `/store` to see if there is anything wrong or misformed

Comment: @mcy: Thanks man, you direct me to another clue. Now, I am dealing with another solution. I'll inform you later. Huge thanks!

Comment: np. for server, the most common issue is having errors while trying to save a file due to virtual/physical path issues or permissions. checking for these might help.

Comment: I've updated the question, please check it out. 
I decide to separate an image files, so I store that files in `imagesFile` variable. Also, I add `boundary` in this case because I got error message `Warning: Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in Unknown on line 0`. 

Still, I have an error. `variantsProd` return `null` in controller. I have no idea what's wrong? Also, I cant use `event.target.files[0];` because I need to store array files.

Comment: @mcy: Seems it's working now. I am using `ajax` instead of `axios`. I will post the answer after everything is okey.

Answer (score 1):

Error 500 means that the server doesn't know how to process your request. Make sure your request matches the format the server expects.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please review my question. I've just update with some detail.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input type="file" ref="identity_card" />
 let identity_card = this.$refs.identity_card.files[0];
 form.append("identity_card_image", identity_card);
       axios.post(`api_url`, form)
         .then(response => {
       })
```

You can try it.

Comment: How can I use `ref`? The file itself located inside `variantsProd` variable. I want send all the data, not just file.

Comment: ref used for individual file identify

Comment: Please review my question. I've just update with some detail.